# How to remove comments/uglify code inside HTML files using Brunch.io

Tags: phoenix-framework, brunch

I'm using Phoenixframework that has Brunch.io integrated in it. I have plenty of  tags with javascript inside my HTML files and HTML comments that I would also like to clean. So, I want Brunch to do it. I know that Phoenix uses a plug-in for javascript minifying and CSS but that leaves HTML javascript and comments.
Is there a configuration/option/plug-in to remove HTML comments? Do I need to use different tools? Do I need to use Regex?

Comment: Well, brunch doesn't handle your HTML files. Are you talking about Javascript comments ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw, brunch clean / minify your javascript files with https://github.com/brunch/uglify-js-brunch. It's a port of https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2.

You have a section comments: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2#keeping-comments-in-the-output.

You should play with the **brunch-config.js** or **brunch-config.coffee** file. I don't know the right syntax but you can play with the default boilerplate given by **uglify-js-brunch** to edit **uglify** options:

```
config =
  plugins:
    uglify:
      mangle: false
      compress:
        global_defs: 
          DEBUG: false
```

Comment: You're right Jeremie. But my main concern is that I use a lot of `<script>` tags in my HTML and I also have plenty of HTML comments that I would like to remove. So my concern is not Javascript/CSS in .js/.css files but inside .html files. I see no simple way of doing that. I'll update my title/question to reflect my html focus.

Comment: Oh, you are speaking about html files served by the folder assets ?

Comment: Yes! In Phoenix divided into templates.

Comment: Well, your templates are not served by Brunch but by Phoenix. It's not related in any way with Brunch.